# Error when using pudb with ipython

Tags: ipython, pudb

I'm trying to use PuDB with ipython as the shell, but when I drop to shell, I get the following error:

```
can't set attribute
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2744, in atexit_operations
    self.reset(new_session=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1132, in reset
    self.displayhook.flush()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py", line 255, in flush
    self.shell.user_ns['_oh'].clear()
KeyError: '_oh'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2744, in atexit_operations
    self.reset(new_session=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1132, in reset
    self.displayhook.flush()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py", line 255, in flush
    self.shell.user_ns['_oh'].clear()
KeyError: '_oh'
```

Version details:

- PuDB 2011.3.1
- IPython 0.12
- Python 2.7.1
- Mac OS X 10.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1241), and should be fixed in IPython 0.12.1 or master.  Does updating to current (0.12.1) IPython help?

Comment: I had to upgrade both ipython to 0.12.1 and pudb to 2012.1. After doing that, it worked.